# Find files > 30 days, Delete and log

Tags: unix

Based on lot of research below is what I have come up with

```
find /Some_Dir -type f -mtime +30 -delete -printf "%TD %p\n" >> /Logfile.txt 2>&1
```

This is doing a good job of deleting the files and it also deletes files with spaces. One concern I have is that this is deleting the files which is just ready only or even files with 000 permission. Is that expected result?

Comment: find just 'find' files depending on some filter mechanisms you specify and do something with it. AFAIK there is no way to tell find to just find files with some kind of 'minimum access level'. So yes, this is expected behavior.

Comment: `rm -f` removed these files, too, if you are the owner. `find` supports `-perm...` to specify a filter for the permission bits, if you want. But this is linux, so check if it applies for unix, too.

Comment: even the AIX version of find supports `-perm ...` (Not certain about Solaris, HPUX, and other unixen ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You are not modifying the files, you are modifying the containing directory.

To forbid deletion of files, you need to either deny write access to the directory, or set the sticky bit (more accurately but less mnemonically known as the "restricted deletion flag") on the directory and ensure the user trying to delete the file does not own the file or the directory.  World-writable directories like `/tmp` will generally have the sticky bit already turned on.

If you just want to change the behavior of the `find` command, use `-writable` or `-perm`.